# Pipeline cpsSCM doesn't take url

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to create pipeline jobs with jenkins dsl. the pipeline job takes the cpsscm if I specify the git url only without branches or credentials. but when I change the brancha nd add credentials, it doesn;t work

```
pipelineJob("foo"){
           definition {
                cpsSCM {
                    git(GIT_URL,BRANCH)
                     }
                }
}
```

The above works. but the following doesn't work

```
 pipelineJob("foobar"){
       definition {
            cpsScm {
                scm{
                    git{
                      branch(BRANCH)
                        remote{
                            credentials('kjsks2304-sid34-234')
                            url(GIT_URL)
                        }
                    }

            }
            scriptPath("JenkinsFile")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

the credentials is the id in the credentials plugin in jenkins. The git repo I am using is a private bitbucket repository

Answer (score 0):

Try here this might help you achieve it, you can use the playground.

https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.workflow.WorkflowDefinitionContext.cpsScm